# How to achieve MySQL Query combining multiple COUNT() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have this data:

```
id      date            userid    result
1       2015-05-01      1          a
2       2015-05-02      1          b
3       2015-05-03      1          b
4       2015-05-03      1          a
5       2015-05-04      1          a
```

I need to get users sorted by result:

```
id    a       b
1       1       1
2       1       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(result = 'win') AS wins, sum(result = 'loss') as losses
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY wins DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT user_id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN result='win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result='loss' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS losses 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY wins DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00ac7/8

Comment: Ah, I see Gordon has already answered. Note that the conditional aggregation he uses is not supported by all databases. But then again, neither is `LIMIT`.